# How to create animation for enter in 1 view and exit from another view in android

Tags: android, android-animation

[image]

As of now view is translate in right side in full screen, but i need to translate view from 1 box to another without appear in space between two boxes.

1. MainActiviy

> ```
> val animFadein =
>             AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this@MainActivity, R.anim.slide_in_right)
>         view.animation = animFadein
>         animFadein.start()
> ```

2. Animation slide_in_right

```
<translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:toXDelta="100%p" /> </set>
```

[![enter image description here][2]][2]